# Renaming multiple files on a folder python of a excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, office-automation

I am pretty new at Python and I want to automate a process that takes a lot of my time but now. I need to rename about 200 + excel files that need to be renamed, but here is the catch they cant be consequential instead they need to be "vlooked up" of a master spreadsheet that contains the names and then name the files exactly how its named on the master spreadsheet. 
So for example:

```
folder I got:

 1. filexxxxFA9261
 2. filexxxxFA3040
 3. filexxxxFA5251
```

and on my master spreadsheet I got:

```
 1. FA9261.4586.56641.1212
 2. FA3040.6589.65555.1516
 3. FA5251.3562.65555.5633
```

basically I just need to vlookup the "FA###" string of the master spreadsheet and rename that file according to what says on the master spreadsheet.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have been trying to look it up everywhere but most renaming is done sequentially and not of a spreadsheet individually.

Here is an exact example on how it should look like:

This is how the file it’s named initially (it varies depending on who sent it):

“ASSET MOVEMENT ***215-156 6C***”

And this is how it needs to look like exactly

146543115.NC251.LM5555989565C2-.***215-156***.NSD6C.556562443.MRO232324564612

Comment: Please post an exact extract of your excel file, so that we know what the file looks like. Also, please provide an example of a filename before and after renaming. Further, do your files not have file extensions?

Comment: Please edit that information into your original post. Formatting is lost in comments

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help using `pandas` to deal with the Excel spreadsheet.  I'm assuming 6C is relevant from the master spreadsheet.

```
import pandas
import shutil

master = pandas.io.excel.read_excel('master.xlsc', 'sheet1')
for r in master:
    key1 = r.split('.')[3]
    key2 = r.split('.')[4][-2:]
    old = 'ASSET MOVEMENT %s %s' % (key1, key2)
    new = r
    shutil.move(old, new)
```