# Rename files with Python, using name map from Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a folder of PDF files (Drawings) that need to be renamed.

The file names are all in the format "x-xxxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx" with the x's being numbers or letters.

I have an excel sheet that lists these files in Column 'A' then in Column 'B' i have the new name that is required for each row in the format "yy-yyyyyy-yyy" with the y's being numbers or letters.

What I would like to do is use Python (preferably Python 3) to rename the files so that the 'y' name is first with the 'x' name appended after with a separator between,

i.e. 
"yy-yyyyyy-yyy -- x-xxxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx"

I'm guessing that Pandas would be used to interact with the Excel file?

Can anyone help?

I'm relatively new to Python so a breakdown and explanation of the steps needed would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have tried the following code that was from an old post by [Jesse Lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223601/renaming-multiple-files-on-a-folder-python-of-a-excel-spreadsheet) which is similar.

```
import pandas
import shutil

IdMapping = pandas.io.excel.read_excel('IdMapping.xlsx', 'sheet1')
for r in master:
    key1 = r.split('.')[3]
    key2 = r.split('.')[4][-2:]
    old = 'ASSET MOVEMENT %s %s' % (key1, key2)
    new = r
    shutil.move(old, new)
```

I understand the first parts but the two lines that refer to key1 and key2 I don't understand. I'm assuming that the square brackets are 'slicing' the string into sections but not sure of the terminology. After that I believe that a new string is put together and them the file renamed with the shutil command.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the help lbellomo, I have tried to use it and got as far as loading the data into the datatframe (i am using spyder so I can see that the data is read). But on the iterrows line I get an error saying incorrect syntax and a carrot symbol pointing to the space after the colon on df.iterrows():     I have no space after and cant figure out why i'm getting the error.

Comment: You've tried? Put code in the question so we can help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you could read the dataframe and have two columns (Where the old name is first and the second second). Also the files to rename are in the same directory.

For the example I'm going to create this test dataframe:

```
data = [{"colum A": "old name 1", "colum B": "new name 1"},
        {"colum A": "old name 2", "colum B": "new name 2"},
        {"colum A": "old name 3", "colum B": "new name 3"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

What we do: iterate over the rows of the dataframe, we read the old name and the new one (Which is the new but `--` plus the old), we print it and finally we change the name of the file.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    old_name = row[1][0]
    new_name = row[1][1] + ' -- ' + old_name
    print("Old name: ", old_name, " New name: ", new_name)
    shutil.move(old, new)
```

Hope this can help you!